# Multiple Block Quotes without using HTML

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, customization, tinymce, css

First of all, I have a client that has no HTML knowledge.
He wants his all his posts to have a certain format where within the post body, he can add multiple pull quotes with different styles.
Note that all the posts would have the same structure.
Any suggestions on how to go about this?
Custom post style? Custom button on TinyMCE?

Anyhelp would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can create shortcode for that

1.make a shortcode unsing [add_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)(functions.php)

```
add_shortcode('bquote','ravs_blockquotes_func')    
    function ravs_blockquotes_func( $atts, $content="" ) {
             extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                  'style' => 'style1'
             ), $atts ) );
        return '<blockquote class="'.$style.'">'.$content.'</blockquote>' 
        }
```

2.now just simply define quote in shortcode(post or page editer)

```
[bquote style="style2"]your quote[/bquote]
```

it's output in html like

```
<blockquote class="style2">your quote</blockquote>
```

3.create as many as class for blockquote style you want.it's easy to use and understand.

**Important Link**:

[WordPress Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)

[WordPress shortcode complete guide](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/)